# ASP.NET Core 3.1 OData PageResult Serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, system.text.json

The `PageResult` response is missing the `nextPageLink` and `count` values when being serialized through `System.Text.Json` (ASP.NET Core 3 default) for the following result:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
  [HttpGet]
  public IActionResult Get()
  {
    var items = new List<string> { "value" };

    var pageResult = new Microsoft.AspNet.OData.PageResult<string>(items, new Uri("http://localhost/foo"), items.Count);

    return Ok(pageResult);
  }
}
```

However when I use the [`Newtonsoft.Json` formatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-3.0#add-newtonsoftjson-based-json-format-support), the result is correct:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
}
```

Result with `System.Text.Json`:

```
[
    "value"
]
```

Result with `Newtonsoft.Json`:

```
{
    "items": [
        "value"
    ],
    "nextPageLink": "http://localhost/foo",
    "count": 1
}
```

Any idea what the reason is for this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

On re-reading the question, this doesn't directly answer why the OP's question of why one formatter does and another does not cause the correct output, but may provide some places for the OP to start looking...

I have also seen interesting behaviour when using OData and Asp.Net Core, it's very difficult to decipher from the online documentation what you should do these days, as most of the docs seem to out of date or for earlier versions of OData. For example, you'll see some references to GetInlineCount() in some documtation, but it appears to have been removed from the API.

For your query, I think you have two options 
Firstly, change your return type to be IQueryable then 
specify the attribute `[EnableQuery(PageSize=10)]`.

Alternatively, keeping what what you have, and using the `PageResult` object:

`return new PageResult<object>(listOfObjects as IEnumerable<object>, Request.GetNextPageLink(5), Request.ODataFeature().TotalCount);`

You can solve the Request.ODataFeature().TotalCount not returning a value by setting the Request.ODataFeature().TotalCountFunc function as follows...

`Request.ODataFeature().TotalCountFunc = () => listOfobjects.Count();`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately both had the same result.
I'm sure the docs will catch up eventually, but I feel your pain.

I'm now thinking this might actually rather be an issue with the `System.Text.Json` formatter...

Answer (score 0):

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : ODataController
{
  [HttpGet]
  [EnableQuery(PageSize=5)]
  public IActionResult Get()
  {
    var items = new List<string> { "value1","value2","value3","value4","value5"  };
 
    return Ok(items);
  }
}
```

Extend your controller with `ODataController` instead of `ControllerBase`. `[EnableQuery]` attribute needs to be added to the method. You can define a `PageSize` if you're doing server side paging.

Comment: Unfortunately that still doesn't give me the desired response. I've updated the question with example responses.